# read data in r (dbReadTable) returns special character for varchar with space

Tags: r, r-dbi

I am using the following code to read data from my SQL database:

```r
library(DBI)
dbReadTable(connect_sql(), Id(schema = "stc", table = "test"))
```

The `stc.test` table looks like

| name | value |
| --- | --- |
| hello | 2 |
| hello world | 3 |

but when I pull these data into R using the code above I get

| name | value |
| --- | --- |
| hello | 2 |
| helloÂ world | 3 |

How can I pull the data into R without the Â before the space in "hello world"?

Comment: How are you so certain that the raw data in the database does not contain a special character? I don't know what DBMS you're using, but with SQL Server for example, one can do `"select cast(name as varbinary(32)) as blob from stc.test"` to look at the raw characters of that string (you may want more filtering if you have many other rows, and 32 is just an example here), then look at the raw data itself. To further that example, a string `"a\nb"` would return `c(0x62, 0x0a, 0x63)`, where the `0x0a` is a carriage-return. What does that return for your string above?

Comment: I create the dataset 'test' in R itself and the name column is a column with characters (no special characters there). I have the idea the Â is created in the translation from sql to R. probably some UTF translation problem

Comment: A temporary fix is: iconv(test$name, from = 'UTF-8', to = 'ASCII//TRANSLIT'). However I would prefer to deal with the issue at the source (so in the dbReadTable statement)

Comment: You're saying that you create the frame in R, upload it to a table in your SQL database, then re-query the data back to R and it now has that special character?

Comment: indeed that seems to be the case

Comment: Can you make this reproducible? I know the concept of your issue seems straight-forward, but I'm confident that I cannot reproduce your conditions perfectly. Please provide the output from `dput(stc.test)` and the code you used to upload to your database. Also please provide the DBMS type itself and the version of your R, `DBI`, and `odbc`. Thanks!

Comment: the code to upload: DBI::dbWriteTable(connect_sql(), Id(schema = "stc", table = "table"), value =  test). the output of dput: c("hello", "helloÂ world"). DBI version 1.1.2, odbc version 1.3.3, R version 4.1.1. The DBMS I am not sure.

Comment: Thanks for the versions. The dput of your _vector_ clearly shows the special character, so the issue is in your R and likely has little or nothing to do with the database?

Comment: Yes. The above is very stylized, in reality my dataset is much bigger and I wonder if I ever created this issue by storing a backup of the table in Excel. If this backup was then used to overwrite the table you could have an issue of translation between R, Excel and SQL.

Comment: I really appreciate that the reprex is small, that's great! Since it is representative of your larger data, though, I think my previous question is still relevant: the characters are present in the vector before sending to the database, in which case this question is mis-tagged (no need for [tag:sql], [tag:odbc], or [tag:dbi]). The use of `iconv` is generally the canonical method for ensuring ascii/utf/unicode conversion/compliance.